# Javascript round value after a random decimal value

Tags: javascript, performance, math, rounding

I'd like to round the value after a random decimal value

```
Example(round up when value > x.90):
18.25478 => 18
18.7545 => 18
18.90 => 19
18.95 = > 19
```

I know the Math.ceil and Math.Floor methods, but i want to combine to one method. And also I read that Math.floor and ceil is slow with to much values (i'm going to convert 3000.000+ values in a list!)

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Will you have any negative numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add `0.1` and use `Math.floor`.

```js
function round(v) {
    return Math.floor(v + 0.1);
}

var array = [
        18.25478, // => 18
        18.7545,  // => 18
        18.90,    // => 19
        18.95,    // => 19 
    ];
  
console.log(array.map(round));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function:

```
function customRound(x) {
  if (x - Math.floor(x) >= 0.9) {
    return Math.ceil(x);
  } else {
    return Math.floor(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more general answer that takes your custom threshold as input, this function will suit your needs better. It also uses `Math.round()` if you are worried about `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()`. It also handles negative numbers. You can fiddle around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0vt7ofw/

```
function customRound(num, threshold) {
  if (num >= 0) {
      return Math.round(num - (threshold - 0.5));
  }
  else {
      return Math.round(num + (threshold - 0.5));
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
customRound(18.7545, 0.9) => 18
customRound(18.9, 0.9) => 19
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a flexible function which will allow for a changeable threshold

```
function roundWithThreshold(threshold, num) {
  return Math[ num % 1 > threshold ? 'ceil' : 'floor' ](num);
}
```

Usage:

```
roundWithThreshold(0.2, 4.4);
```